# Laravel: как правильно заполнять и сбрасывать БД при тестировании?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть простой тест, который ничего не тестирует, просто забивает БД (это для примера):

```
class SuggestionRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    public function test_insert_checkInsertInDbAndCheckResult()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        $this->seed(TestDatabaseSeeder::class);
    }

    public function test_delete_checkDeleteFromDb()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        $this->seed(TestDatabaseSeeder::class);

    }
}
```

В самом сидере генерация с разными зависимостями и внешними ключами.

Если тестировать в памяти и на sqlite - все норм.

Но как только тестирование начинается на postgres - начинается какая-то каша. Второй тест банально не может засидироваться, пишет ошибку внешних ключей. Если удалить первый - то второй запустится. Хотя по идее каждый метод - независимый тест.

Как я понял, причина в  RefreshDatabase. Что он там как-то оборачивает все в транзакции, и поэтому все крашится.

Собственно вопрос - как правильно тестировать настоящую БД, а не в мемори?